# Linear Transformation: I don't even know what I don't know

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The "Example" is If A is m x n, the matrix transformation $T_A = R^n \rightarrow R^m$, A is a linear transformation

Solution is
We have $T_A(x) = Ax$ for all $x$ in $R^n$, so
$T_A(x + y) = A(x + y) = Ax + Ay = T_A(x) + T_A(y)$ and
$T_A(ax) = A(ax) = a(Ax) = aT_A(x)$

It follows "Theorem 1", so I don't even have an appropriate title for it.

My question is... what's R? What's $R^n$ and $R^m$? Why are they n and m (I mean in relation to the size of the matrix m x n)?

And what does the solution (x + y) have anything to do with anything?

Please help. Can someone help me decode this?

Comment: He is checking the definition of linear transformation on the example he defined.

Comment: Ok, but can you tell me what R is?

Comment: It is most likely a ring or perhaps moreover a field.  But we can't tell for sure

Comment: I mean, how are we supposed to know lol, you're the one with the book

Comment: I suppose $R$ means the reals here.

Comment: Is it $R$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The second one. It's obviously some type of matrix. But I don't know why it's R^n and R^m. It's a transformation of matrix of size column to a matrix of size row of A? And what the heck is x in R^n? -_-?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ stands for set of real numbers. It is a standard notation.

Comment: Why are people downvoting?  OP is obviously super confused about this and wants to learn

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (I don't know) $R$ stands for $\mathbb{R}$, the field of real numbers.

$R^n$ is meant to be the set of $n$ by $1$ matrices with entries in $R$.  For example, $R^3$ is the set of matrices of the form

$$ v = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$$

There's an obvious way to add and scalar multiply such objects.  For example, if $\lambda \in R$, then $\lambda \cdot v$ means

$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda x \\ \lambda y \\ \lambda z \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus $R^n$ is a vector space.  If $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix, then $Av$ means you multiply the matrices $A$ and $v$ together.  When you do this, you get an $m$ by $1$ matrix (so you get something in $R^m$).

So what's going on here is you are thinking of the matrix $A$ as a function from $R^n$ to $R^m$.  You start with something in $R^n$, multiply it on the left by $A$, you get something in $R^m$.  And this function is *linear*, meaning the following: if you add two things in $R^n$, and apply the function, that's the same thing as applying the function to each of the things, and then adding the corresponding things in $R^m$.  And if you multiply something in $R^n$ by a scalar, and then apply the function to that, that's the same thing as applying the function, and then multiplying by the scalar).

> Why are they n and m (I mean in relation to the size of the matrix m x n)?

Because, if $a, b, c$ are positive integers, then multiplying an $a$ by $b$ matrix with a $b$ by $c$ matrix gets you an $a$ by $c$ matrix.

**Example**: let $m = 3, n = 2$, and let

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \\ 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then you can think of $A$ as a function from $R^2$ to $R^3$.  For example, you input the element $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$, check that you get $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -2 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$.

If you're still confused, go to office hours.